# Getting data from selected dataGridView to string

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I'd like to extract a selected data from dataGridView to string variable but I seem to have gone wrong somewhere in the code. How do I go about this? Below is what I'd written but it doesn't seem to be right.

```
            if ( dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != null)
        {
            string itemid = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string name = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string description = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); 
        }
```

Comment: probably `if ( dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)` would be better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.
Make sure change the property Multiselect = false and SelectionMode = FullRowSelect to ensure gets only one selection.

SelectedRows.Count is always 0 until you select one

```
if ( dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        string itemid = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string name = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string description = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); 
    }
```